# Rails 5 find adult users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got pretty old App where I have to create rake task to find all users over 18 and update flags from `adult: false` to `adult: true`. I'm wondering what I should use in a rather old version of Rails (I have Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4 on board) to keep the highest performance?

What I have for now is a sidekiq worker with, I think, some syntax error:

```
class MinorsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    adults = User.where(adults: false).where('date_of_birth >= 18, ?', ((Time.zone.now - date_of_birth.to_time) / 1.year.seconds))
    adults.update(adult: true)
  end
end
```

But this code gives me an error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `date_of_birth' for main:Object

Comment: Why on earth do you have a boolean column for this in the first place?

Comment: @max I'd like to know that too, it's a pretty old app and code legacy is pretty big as you see

Comment: `where('date_of_birth >= 18, ?', ((Time.zone.now - date_of_birth.to_time) / 1.year.seconds))` This is what's causing the issue because you don't have any variable named `date_of_birth` in perform method.

Comment: @AbdulRehman yeah, I defined a separate scope for that but it seems to be lame: `scope :adults, -> { where('date_of_birth <= ?', Time.now.getutc.to_date - 18.years) }`

Comment: I think it will work like this `scope :adults, -> { where('date_of_birth <= ?', 18.years.ago) }`

Comment: @max Because if being adult is important it’s faster than doing date math (especially if it’s indexed). For large systems the difference can be huge.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following. This would update all the matched records in 1 update statement.

If you are concern with db IO, you can batch it.

```rb
# in user.rb
class User
  scope :adult, -> {  where('date_of_birth <= ?', 18.years.ago) }
end

# in your worker file

class MinorsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    update_all
    # for update in batches, use #update_all_in_batches
  end

  private

  def update_all
    User.adult.where(adult: false).update_all(adult: true)
  end

  def update_all_in_batches
    User.adult.where(adult: false).in_batches(each: 1000) do |users|
      users.update_all(adult: true)
      sleep 2
    end
  end
end
```